# Angular CLI + Flask app runs and displays with ng serve, but not displayed through flask

Tags: python, angular, flask

I am creating a web app with an angular front-end and a flask back-end. When I run the app using ng serve, it works as intended, but when I run it using this app.py, it only shows the default angular page with "*name of project* app is running!" and the various other angular links and such.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

Am I missing something? Why is it not just displaying the app on the flask server?

I'm pretty new to all this, so I'm sorry if its a redundant question or if its a silly mistake.

Thank you

Comment: because your front end and back end are not binding when you are running only the flask app, ng serve act as a binder between your front end and back end here, if you want to just use the flask only then try work on jinja templating and bootstrap . [this may help you](https://auth0.com/blog/using-python-flask-and-angular-to-build-modern-apps-part-1/)

Comment: I am not 100% sure of this. But along the lines of what @sahasrara62 mentioned I believe what you have to do is map the port of app.run() to the port running on ng serve

Comment: So building the application again resulted in something different, now, the index.html file is calling the javascript files that were created and placed into my static folder, but chrome console shows a 404 error, even though the files are in the directory. Strange

Answer (score 1):

angular has its own server for rendering . flask can be use as back end for your angular front end . you should communicate through HttpClientmodule from angular as front to predetermined end points from flask . for example 'localhost:3000/products'

these two technology is seperated although can link with http protocol ,

but if you realy want to mix them , and serve your build angular as a template , so you want to link all js extention file that came out from build command in your index file . something like base template and static file like css and so on .

you specify address of dist folder , folder that ng build create these file and link them in link tag in base template .